# Difference between two time zones in Excel

Tags: excel

I have one time zone in A1 (example *Minus* 05:30) and another time zone in B1 (*Plus* 03:00). To calculate the difference between A1 and B1 and to display in hours and minutes in cell C1, I have written `=(A1-B1)*-1`in cell C1.
But the main issue is, I cannot put minus -05:30 in A1 for this formula to work. There is no inbuilt cell formatting I can choose. Is there any solution please.

I am adding additional comments to the main Question :- cells in A1 and B1 can have minus values because time zone is calculated from GMT time. GMT is zero and place which is east of GMT will have minus and west of GMT will have plus time difference. Example if you are in Panama, your time is minus 05:30 and if you are in India, your time is plus 05:30. I am trying to calculate time difference between any two time zones.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why `=(A1-B1)*-1`? Why not: `=B1-A1` in cell C1. Then you don't need minus time in A1.

Or

You may use [LibreOffice Calc](https://www.libreoffice.org/) instead of excel to display negative time format, thus solve your problem.

If you insist to use excel, then there is no negative time format by default. But there are couple complicated routes ([see here](https://www.computergaga.com/blog/display-negative-time-in-excel/)) to display negative time.

Comment: cells in A1 and B1 can have minus time because time zone is calculated from GMT or UTC time. GMT is zero and place which is east of GMT will have minus and west of GMT will have plus time difference. Example if you are in Panama, your time is minus 05:30 and if you are in India, your time is plus 05:30. I am trying to calculate time difference between any two time zones.

Comment: see my updated answer above